# Testing version specifiers in scripts

Tags: python, packaging

I'd like to use the python packaging systems version specifier logic myself but am struggling to find the right internal APIs.

Given a version specifier `'>=1.8.*,<=1.9.*'`, which you might find in a pip requirements file, how can I test that a given version number - say `1.9.0.1` - satisfies the requirement or not?

Comment: Are you looking for `pip`'s [`version.py`](https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/7228a6a1fae418bcfac4d9f95bafcffe6b7abe16/pip/_vendor/packaging/version.py)? This does the work of parsing the versions into classes that implement comparisons.

Comment: See also [`specifiers.py`](https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/7228a6a1fae418bcfac4d9f95bafcffe6b7abe16/pip/_vendor/packaging/specifiers.py).

Comment: `SpecifierSet` in specifiers.py is what I'm looking for, thank you